Error (not allowed) when trying to hit the backend
Hi I uploaded my MERN (BTW I am using Mysql instead of mongo DB) app to the VPS everything was working fine in my local environment but when I deployed it on the VPS and try to communicate with the Backend Like getting the data from the API it gives me 405 not allowed error in my console you can try https://courierlink.com.au/CalQuote fill the details and click on get quote and in the console it gives me the 405 not allowed error how can I fix that and why it is happening I checked the other questions related to that on stackoverflow but nothing seems to work
Here is my nginx config file see if that helps


 server {
    server_name courierlink.com.au www.courierlink.com.au;

    location / {
        root /var/www/CourierWorld/frontend/build;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/courierlink.com.au/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/courierlink.com.au/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
 server {
    if ($host = courierlink.com.au) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name courierlink.com.au www.courierlink.com.au;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}




you use the acronym MERN yet all you've shown is an NGINX config for a static site
